# Foreach in multidimensional array doesnt work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, multidimensional-array, laravel-5.7

I have two methods for looking into directories and making a tree.

```php
public function getFolders($path)
{
    $folders = \Storage::disk('public')->directories($path);

    return count($folders) > 0 ? $folders : [];
}

public function getTree($path = '')
{
    if (count($tree = $this->getFolders($path)) === 0) {
        return ['nema'];
    }

    $arr = [];
    foreach ($tree as $value) {
        $folder = str_replace($path, '', $value);
        if (count(explode('/', $folder)) === 1) {
            if (count($this->getFolders($value)) > 0) {
                $arr[$folder] = $this->getTree($value . '/');
            } else {
                $arr[$folder] = $folder;
            }
        }
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

When I `dd($arr)` I get:

```
array:1 [▼
  "files" => array:2 [▼
    422 => array:1 [▶]
    "shares" => array:2 [▼
      "sasic" => array:2 [▼
        "daasdasd" => "daasdasd"
        "thumbs" => "thumbs"
      ]
      "thumbs" => "thumbs"
    ]
  ]
]
```

But when I try this:

```php
$test = 0;
foreach($arr as $folder) 
{  
    if(is_array($folder)){
        $test = $test + 1;
    }
}

return $test; // returns 0 like there is zero arrays
```

The strange thing is that if I use `echo` in a `foreach`, it doesn't go from top to bottom but instead in some mixed order.

Any ideas?

I am trying to make the menu tree from only directories within some folder in Laravel storage public disk.

Update: I added `$test` in the loop here by writing this part of the code. Didn't copy that so, that's not answering my question as to why the values are not in an array.

Comment: Why do you want an array at all? You should learn to do things easier with iterators.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use "recursion" in this case.

```
function CountFolders($folder_array,$amount)
{
    foreach($folder_array as $folder)
    {
        if(is_array($folder))
        {
            $amount = $amount + 1;
            $amount=CountFolders($folder,$amount);

        }
    }
    return $amount;
}

echo'Total folders: '.CountFolders($arr,0);
```

This function checks and if found an array calls SELF on it and repeats until all arrays counted.

This way you don't need to know the max "deepness" of array.

Comment: I added that in here I have same output that non of values is an array.... Could you add new laravel app and few folders inside storage and try to see what I mean?

Comment: Also if you look the array output, you can see that main array item has array with two items. So even if I added $test in foreach it should return 1 because first item has an array.

Comment: You are right it looks only to first "level" of array without a recursion.

Comment: Rewrited the answer, try this solution. Your $arr array should be fine for it.

Comment: You dont understand, it fails in if() check is value an array. Even if it is an array it returns like it is not

Answer (score 1):

You should use PHP's OOP approach using iterator classes:

```
class DirectoryArrayTreeIterator extends RecursiveDirectoryIterator
{
  function current()
  {
    return ($this->isDir()) ? iterator_to_array($this->getChildren()) : $this->getFilename();
  }
}

$iter = new DirectoryArrayTreeIterator('/path/to/folder', DirectoryArrayTreeIterator::SKIP_DOTS | DirectoryArrayTreeIterator::KEY_AS_FILENAME);
var_dump(iterator_to_array($iter));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have nothing...
You can use same recursion, but don't need to store anything to array.

```
<?php
```

You need a function and I suggest to use URL and AMOUNT parameters

```
function CountFolders($url,$amount)
{
```

Function gets list of files and folders in current folder

```
$urlm=scandir($url);
```

Loops trough them

```
foreach($urlm as $folder)
{
```

Checks if it found a directory or a file.

If it is a directory and not a link to go back ("." and ".."), counts it to amount of directories.

```
if((is_dir($url.'/'.$folder))&&($folder!='.')&&($folder!='..'))
{
    $amount = $amount + 1;
```

Optional, to show a list of directories found.

Here you can store directory name or URL to array if needed.

```
//echo $url.'/'.$folder.' - <strong>DIR</strong><hr>';
```

If it is a directory, check it for another directories in it

```
        $amount=CountFolders($url.'/'.$folder,$amount);
    }
  }
```

Function returns amount of directories in a directory.

```
  return $amount;
}
```

Lastly show the result

```
echo'Total directories: '.CountFolders('../TestFolder',0);
?>
```

And all code in one place:

```
<?php

function CountFolders($url,$amount)
{
    $urlm=scandir($url);    
    foreach($urlm as $folder)
    {
        if((is_dir($url.'/'.$folder))&&($folder!='.')&&($folder!='..'))
        {
            $amount = $amount + 1;

            echo $url.'/'.$folder.' - <strong>DIR</strong><hr>';

            $amount=CountFolders($url.'/'.$folder,$amount);
        }
    }
    return $amount;
}

echo'Total folders: '.CountFolders('../TestFolder',0);

?>
```